# Javascript class encapsulation behaviour

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

Can somebody explain me this javascript behaviour? I create 2 objects (`x`, `y`) and I call `x.m()` to modify private variable `b` on `x`. Then I call printing methods on both `x` and `y` and it produces following output. The output differs if the printing method `p()` is defined as a `this` property (1) or as a prototype (2).

`this.p` definition acts as expected: 2 objects have two private variables, modifying `b` property on `x` does not affect `y`'s `b` property. But with `A.prototype.p` definition, `b` property seems to be static variable common for both objects `x` and `y`.

Described behaviour in code:

```
function A() {
  var b = "bbb";

  function f() {
    b = "ccc";
  }

  // 1)
  this.p = function() {
    console.log(b);
  };

  // 2)
  //A.prototype.p = function() {
  //  console.log(b);
  //};

  A.prototype.m = function() {
    f();
  };
}

var x = new A();
var y = new A();

x.m();
x.p();
y.p();
```

produces:

```
// 1)
bbbb
ccc

// 2)
//ccc
//ccc
```

Comment: Dont set the prototype method in the constructor of `A`. This way, you will override the prototype method `m` and `p` every time you create an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are overriding the prototype method `p` (as well as `m`) in the constructor of `A`, which means every time you create an instance the prototype method will change. All instances of `A` will then use the same method, which is the one of the last created instance.

Have a look at this example which should show the behaviour you expect for your code:

```
function A() {
  this.b = "bbb";
}

A.prototype.p = function() {
  console.log(this.b);
};

A.prototype.m = function() {
  this.b = "ccc";
};


var x = new A(),
  y = new A();

x.m();
x.p();
y.p();
```

Comment: Ok, but I need 'b' to be a private property.

Comment: A common convention is to prefix private properties with an underscore, so you would name it `this._b`. To have truly private properties, you have to make use of a closure like in your example version 1. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties

Comment: Using closure (and not prototype) seems to be a way to go for me. THX